# Symfony Validator modify form fields

Tags: symfony, validation, symfony-forms

I have a validator that looks like this:

```
    class ValidUSPSAddressValidator extends ConstraintValidator
    {
        public function validate($protocol, Constraint $constraint)
        {
            $verify = new USPSAddressVerify('*******');
            $uspsAddress = new USPSAddress();
            $apartment = $protocol->getApartment();
            $address = $protocol->getAddress();
            $city = $protocol->getCity();
            $state = $protocol->getState();
            $zip = $protocol->getZip();


            $uspsAddress->setApt($apartment);
            $uspsAddress->setAddress($address);
            $uspsAddress->setCity($city);
            $uspsAddress->setState($state);
            $uspsAddress->setZip5($zip);
            $uspsAddress->setZip4('');
            $verify->addAddress($uspsAddress);

            $verify->verify();
            $response = $verify->getArrayResponse();
            $responseAddress = $response['AddressValidateResponse']['Address'];


            if ($verify->isError()) {
                $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                    ->addViolation();
            }else{
                $protocol->setAddress($responseAddress['Address2']);
                $protocol->setCity($responseAddress['City']);
                $protocol->setState($responseAddress['State']);
                $protocol->setZip($responseAddress['Zip5']);

                //****** THE BELOW IF ******************
                if($responseAddress['Address2'] != $address || $responseAddress['City'] != $city || $responseAddress['State'] != $state || $responseAddress['Zip5'] != $zip){
                    $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->verify)
                        ->addViolation();
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Looking at the final IF statement and code within it... I am trying set the fields to what the USPS response was and the validator basically gives the user one last chance to see the updated data modify the fields and which will then re-validate again and as long as the data matches USPS data exactly it will persist it. The problem is that the protocol->setXXXXX() sets the data on the object to be persisted, but just doesn't show the data in the fields when it re-displays the form...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of Validator is to validate Object, maybe try using [data transformers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html) or [form listeners](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html) or even [event listeners](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html), and skip doing this kind of logic inside of validator.

Comment: I ended up adding to Form Listener, "PRE_SUBMIT". It does what I need however feel like this solution, at least the way I'm doing it is a little bit of a hack... When the response comes back from USPS I alter all the fields to match and if any of that data changed from what the user initially submitted I add an error to the form just basically saying to double check the address. At this point the user would hopefully accept the corrected address and just submit again... Any other pointers to improve this process?